# laravel/eloquent mutators/accessors in a pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

Well, I think the title explains most of it.  Lets get right into it!

Blank Model:

```
class Blank extends Eloquent 
{

    protected $table = 'blanks';

    protected $softDelete = true;

    protected $hidden = array();

    /**
     * Get associated jobs.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Job')->withPivot('status', 'inventory', 'sizes', 'mill', 'po', 'location', 'ordered_at', 'expected_at', 'note')->withTimestamps();
    }

    /**
     * Blanks sizes accessor
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function getSizesAttribute($value)
    {
        return json_decode($this->pivot->sizes);
    }

    /**
     * Blanks sizes mutator
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setSizesAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->pivot->attributes['sizes'] = json_encode($this->pivot->sizes);
    }

}
```

Job Model:

```
class Job extends Eloquent
{

    protected $table = 'jobs';

    protected $softDelete = true;

    protected $hidden = array();

    /**
     * Get associated blank.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function blanks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Blank')->withPivot('status', 'inventory', 'sizes', 'mill', 'po', 'location', 'ordered_at', 'expected_at', 'note')->withTimestamps();
    }

    /**
     * Blanks sizes accessor
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function getSizesAttribute($value)
    {
        return json_decode($this->pivot->sizes);
    }

    /**
     * Blanks sizes mutator
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setSizesAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->pivot->attributes['sizes'] = json_encode($this->pivot->sizes);
    }
}
```

Attaching Code:

```
$job->blanks()->attach($blank->id,[
    'status'      => Input::get('status'),
    'inventory'   => Input::get('inventory'),
    //'sizes'       => $sizes,
    'mill'        => Input::get('mill'),
    'po'          => Input::get('po'),
    'location'    => Input::get('location'),
    'ordered_at'  => Carbon::parse(Input::get('ordered_at'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'expected_at' => Carbon::parse(Input::get('expected_at'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'note'        => Input::get('note'),
]);
```

The mutator is not being called at all.. Any ideas?

Comment: which mutator are you expecting to be called... and when?

Comment: I would assume that the mutator 'setSizesAttribute' on the jobs model would be called because i am setting 'sizes'. It is currently commented out in the code so you can see where it is called.

Comment: that is merely in an array, the mutators only get called when you're calling that value off the model instance directly. If you want to use mutators on a pivot, you'd need to have a new model explicitly for the pivot.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like that **not possible** to do this through **`::attach()`** method.

**But** maybe you would like to use '[Defining A Custom Pivot Model](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)'

```
public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists)
{
    return new YourCustomPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
}
```

So, you can define your own pivot class with mutators:

```
class BlankJobPivot extends Eloquent
{
    // ...

    /**
     * Blanks sizes accessor
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function getSizesAttribute($value)
    {
        return json_decode($value);
    }

    /**
     * Blanks sizes mutator
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setSizesAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['sizes'] = json_encode($value);
        return $value; // return for multiple assignment statement:  $arr = $pivot->sizes = array(12, 23, 34);
    }
}
```

And than you can use getters:

```
$blank->jobs[$i]->pivot->sizes; // - ::getSizesAttribute() will called ( I hope :) )
```

And maybe you will find a way to `save` / `attach` through the `setSizesAttribute` mutator.

Good luck.